# MyUnity configuration not working in 11.10

Tags: unity

MyUnity / CompizConfig with Unity plugin doesn't seem to be working anymore on fresh installations of Ubuntu. I did some recent Ubuntu installations on a couple of machines and when trying to modify things like launcher icon size / behavior etc. using MyUnity / CompizConfig, the changes don't seem to be applied anymore, they just stay at default.

Answer (score 1):

Into a fresh install it's possible.

Logout and then log back in, and your settings should have taken affect.